# ExtJs IE7: 'events is null or not an object' when I closed window

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-7

I am using grid component, when users double click on records - open window, here is my code:

```
var gridPanel = Ext.create('AB.ins.Grid', {
    title:'Grid Panel',
    allowBlank: true,
    style: {
      cursor: 'default'
    },
    store: insuranceStore,
    columns: [
      {header:'№', dataIndex: 'id',width: 45, align: 'right'},
      {header:'Name', dataIndex: 'fio', width: 250},
    ],
    dockedItems: [{
      xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
      store: insuranceStore,
      itemId: 'pagingbar',
      dock: 'bottom',
      displayInfo: true
    }],
    listeners: {
      itemdblclick: function(obj,record,item,index,event,options) {      
        var testshow = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
          width: 500,
          height: 600,
          modal: true,
          title: 'Test window'
        });
        testshow.show();
      }
    }
});
```

In FF this code works fine. In IE7 this code works, but when i closed window in the third or fourth time IE show errors 'events is null or not an object'. What occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't like trailing commas, and it usually cause bizarre error messages. In later versions of IE it doesn't seem to be as big a problem.

Change your columns definition to this...

```
columns: [
  {header:'№', dataIndex: 'id',width: 45, align: 'right'},
  {header:'Name', dataIndex: 'fio', width: 250}
],
```

Notice the trailing comma on the second item has been removed

Comment: it helped me a lot in resolving the issue. thank you